# How to fetch data from multiple db from the node.js in frontend react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below code, where I have to get data from all the files in the same DB. Node.js is running at the backend. When I try the below code, I always get the last fetch, can anyone please help me how to fix this.
The below is from the react JS frontend.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("This Worked Sucessfully")
        this.getDataFromDb();
        if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
          let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
          this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
        }
      }

      getDataFromDb = () => {fetch('http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/passed')
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(res => this.setState({ passed: res.data }));
      };

      getDataFromDb = () => {fetch('http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/failed')
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(res => this.setState({ failed: res.data }));
      };

      getDataFromDb = () => {fetch('http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/all')
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(res => this.setState({ data2: res.data }));
      };
      render() {
        const primaryColor = getColor('primary');
        const secondaryColor = getColor('secondary');
        const { passed, failed, data2 } = this.state
```

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to fire all your requests simultaneously but wait that all of them get resolved before udpating the state (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see by your code, you seem to be re-writing your `goGetDataFromDB` two times. Try changing the names of each function or, the way you call them. You can also take advantage of `Promise.all` to group the results of each call into a single return handle.

[Check this link for the documentation of `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

You could refactor your current code to something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000)
      this.setState({intervalIsSet: true })
    }
  }

  getDataFromDb = () => {
    Promise.all([
      'http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/passed',
      'http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/failed',
      'http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/all'
    ].map(url => (
      fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(res => res.data)
      )
    )).then(([passed, failed, data2]) => 
      this.setState({ passed, failed, data2 })
    );
  }

  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```

I tried to keep as much as your code as possible so you could notice the differences.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried the same, unfortunately that is also not working this time none of them "passed" / "failed" / "data2" had any result.
What could have been wrong.. when I try like 
'''
  getDataFromDb = () => {fetch('http://172.24.78.202:3001/api/failed')
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ all: res.data }));
  };
'''
It works.. still not working together :( any ideas please.

Comment: I also tried this
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("This Worked Sucessfully")
    this.getDataFromDb();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
    }
  }
   componentDidMount2() {
    console.log("This Worked Sucessfully")
    this.getDataFromDb2();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet2) {
      let interval2 = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb2, 1000);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet2: interval2 });
    }
  }

Comment: The only thing I see differences between my code and yours is that the data you are looking for is inside a key called `data` inside the JSON response. I modified the example showing you this. It should work. Check that the requests are sent and their responses.